# How to get complete xml from string in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I get a response from a http call as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://xxx.abc.in"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:LoginResponse><return><SessionID>abc12345</SessionID><ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Successful</ResponseMessage></return></ns1:LoginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now since this is string , i cant do a xml diff. 
When trying to convert it into xml using ElementTree  , i get just the root

```
tree = etree.fromstring(responseJson)
```

result :

```
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x3414c90>
```

Please suggest how to extact the complete xml (without having to save it as a file). I am new to xmls ,so not even sure if i am doing the right operations

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexes or even functions like [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) or [iter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter), below a little example about how to iterate the content of `<return>`

```
for item in tree[0][0][0]:
    print item
```